# qual a diferença em usar #minha_div ou div#minha_div

Tags: html, css

gostaria de saber se tem alguma diferença na hora da estilização de uma página usando `div#minha_div` ou `#minha_div`, e outra diferença se influencia colocar o caminho todo da div que vai ser estilizada por exemplo `#wrapper #topo #menu` e qual a diferença entre elas ? e se tiver alguma diferença isso tambem influencia ? `#wrapper #topo div#menu` e outra coisa que eu queria saber, é se tem alguma propriedade que defina a altura do `border-right` ou `border-left`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **div#minha_div** e **#minha_div**

No primeiro caso você está selecionando uma `div` que tem a `id` `#minhadiv`. Ex.:

```
<div id="minha_div"></div>
```

No segundo, você está selecionando **qualquer elemento** que possua a `id` `#minhadiv`, que não precisa ser necessariamente uma `div`. Ex.:

```
<input id="minha_div">
```

> **#wrapper #topo #menu**

Aqui você está fazendo uma seleção por hierarquia: o `#menu` é filho de `#topo` que é filho de `#wrapper`.

Esta forma de seleção é desnecessária neste caso porque como um `id` deve ser único na página, você pode simplesmente selecionar apenas o `#menu` direto, sem mencionar seus pais e avôs.

Geralmente se faz isso com classes ou tags, porque você pode querer selecionar uma classe ou tag que se encontra no `#menu` mas não quer selecionar uma que exista em outro lugar. Ex.:

```
#menu li{
   color: red;
}
#menu .ativo{
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

> **Altura da borda**

A borda só possui a propriedade `border[-top|right|bottom|left]-width` que nada mais é que a espessura. Se quiser criar uma *pseudo-borda* para dar um efeito de que as bordas *right* ou *left* tenham uma "altura" que não seja a normal, poderá recorrer a <strike>gambiarras</strike> pseudo-elementos, como `::before` e `::after`.

Answer (score 2):

**1 - gostaria de saber se tem alguma diferença na hora da estilização de uma página usando `div#minha_div` ou `#minha_div`...**

A diferença é que quando você coloca uma tag em HTML na frente do id ou da classe esta só será executada através da tag. Exemplo:

```css
div#bgRed {
 background-color: red;
 padding: 30px;
}

#bgYellow {
 background-color: yellow;
 padding: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id="bgYellow" >
 Div 1 - Yellow
</div>

<div id="bgRed">
 Div 2 - Red
</div>

<p id="bgYellow"> Paragrafo 1 - Yellow</p>
<p id="bgRed"> Paragrafo 2 - Red</p>
```

Repare que mesmo a tag `<p>`do paragrafo 2 tendo o mesmo id `bgRed` da `div`, apenas a div recuperou o estilo. Pois está configurado para ser assim.

**2 - e outra diferença se influencia colocar o caminho todo da `div` que vai ser estilizada por exemplo `#wrapper #topo #menu` e qual a diferença entre elas**

Isto é importante quando você precisa executar um estilo específico para essa visualização. A diferença é quando seu layout tiver `menu` dentro de um `topo` que estará dentro de um `wrapper` este estilo será executado. Repare nesse exemplo:

```css
#wrapper, #topo, #menu {
 color: red;
}

#wrapper #topo #menu  {
 color: black;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" >
 wrapper
</div>

<div id="topo">
 topo
</div>

<div id="menu">
 menu
</div>

<div id="wrapper" >
 <div id="topo" >
  <div id="menu" >
   menu
  </div>
 </div>
</div>

<div id="menu">
 menu
</div>
```

As cores foram configuradas em red para todas as divs, utilizando ",". Depois é inserido um estilo específico que mudará a cor apenas naquele caso. Repare o menu quando está sozinho, ou seja, forda das outras divs, ele recupera a configuração anterior.

**3 - outra coisa que eu queria saber, é se tem alguma propriedade que defina a altura do `border-right` ou `border-left`**

Não existe. Mas tem como fazer. Veja:

```css
#wrapper {
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 position: relative;
 xborder-bottom: 2px solid #f51c40;
 background: red;
}

#wrapper:after {
  content : "";
  position: absolute;
  right    : 0;
  z-index: 100;
  top  : 0;
  width  : 3px; /* aqui seria a largura da borda */
  height   : 50%; /* aqui é a altura da borda */
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper" >
 wrapper
</div>
```